# Share variables across scripts

Tags: python

I have 2 separate scripts working with the same variables.

To be more precise, one code edits the variables and the other one uses them (It would be nice if it could edit them too but not absolutely necessary.)

This is what i am currently doing:
When code 1 edits a variable it dumps it into a json file.
Code 2 repeatedly opens the json file to get the variables.

This method is really not elegant and the while loop is really slow.

How can i share variables across scripts?

My first scripts gets data from a midi controller and sends web-requests.
My second script is for LED strips (those run thanks to the same midi controller). Both script run in a "while true" loop.

I can't simply put them in the same script since every webrequest would slow the LEDs down. I am currently just sharing the variables via a json file.

If enough people ask for it i will post the whole code but i have been told not to do this

Comment: Any chance to put the code into a single script? Or to pipe the variables as output from the first script to the second?

Comment: When you say multitask, do you mean `multithreading`?

Comment: Use a key value store such as memcached, redis, bdb, or even sqlite if you can.

Comment: Please edit your post to guve more details about what each script does and they should run in parallel. There are many possible solutions depending on the context so it's impossible to tell you which is the right one without more informations...

Comment: It looks like you want to work with [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). You'd use a `main` that will act as glue between your two scripts. You might also look at [how to share data between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) -- I agree with @brunodesthuilliers though, there are many possible solutions.

Comment: Sounds like all that's required here is multithreading.  The two scripts should be combined into a single script with two threads.  Then the two threads could share the relevant data in memory.  The two threads would have to be smart about how they shared the data.  This might involve some thread coordination mutexes.  The OP says "I can't simply put them in the same script since every webrequest would slow the LEDs down.", but this shouldn't be true with two threads running independently.  Anything more than this...multiprocessing...is going to add unnecessary complexity and overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the information you provided, meaning...

> Both script run in a "while true" loop.
>
> I can't simply put them in the same script since every webrequest would slow the LEDs down.

To me, you have 2 choices :

1. Use a client/server model. You have 2 machines. One acts as the server, and the second as the client. The server has a script with an infinite loop that consistently updates the data, and you would have an API that would just read and expose the current state of your file/database to the client. The client would be on another machine, and as I understand it, it would simply request the current data, and process it.
2. Make a single [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) script. Each script would run on a separate 'thread' and would manage its own memory. As you also want to share variables between your two programs, you could pass as argument an object that would be shared between both your programs. See [`this resource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to help you.

Note that there are more solutions to this. For instance, you're using a JSON file that you are consistently opening and closing (that is probably what takes the most time in your program). You could use a real Database that could handle being opened only once, and processed many times, while still being updated.

Answer (score 0):

a [`Manager` from `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) lets you do this sort thing pretty easily

first I simplify your "midi controller and sends web-request" code down to something that just sleeps for random amounts of time and updates a variable in a managed dictionary:

```
from time import sleep
from random import random

def slow_fn(d):
    i = 0
    while True:
        sleep(random() ** 2)
        i += 1
        d['value'] = i
```

next we simplify the "LED strip" control down to something that just prints to the screen:

```
from time import perf_counter

def fast_fn(d):
    last = perf_counter()
    while True:
        sleep(0.05)
        value = d.get('value')
        now = perf_counter()
        print(f'fast {value} {(now - last) * 1000:.2f}ms')
        last = now
```

you can then run these functions in separate processes:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Manager() as manager:
    d = manager.dict()

    procs = []
    for fn in [slow_fn, fast_fn]:
        p = mp.Process(target=fn, args=[d])
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

the "fast" output happens regularly with no obvious visual pauses